# What am I doing wrong on this question about "varies directly" and "varies inversely"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't get this problem:

$R$ varies directly as $S$ and inversely as $T$. When $R = \frac{4}{3}, T = \frac{9}{14}$, $S = \frac{3}{7}$. Find $S$ when $R = \sqrt{48}$ and $T = \sqrt{75}$.

My attempt:

We know

$$ R = c_1 S$$

and

$$ R = \frac{c_2}{T}$$

Plugging things in, we get $c_1 = \frac{28}{9}$ and $c_2 = \frac{6}{7}$. Now, we just solve for $S$.

$$ \sqrt{48} = \frac{6}{7} S$$

$$ 4 \sqrt{3} = \frac{6}{7} S$$

$$ 2 \sqrt{3} = \frac{3}{7} S$$

$$S = \frac{14}{3} \sqrt{3} $$

But, as far as I know, the correct answer appears to be $30$. What am I doing wrong? Am I getting wrong the definition of "directly" and "inversely"?

Comment: It should be $R=kS/T$. Solve for $k$ from the first case then plug into the second case.

Comment: So you downvote the last answer to your last question, so you can delete it?  How bout give up the "fake proofs" you fail on.

Comment: @amWhy Okay, I'll drop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t treat the relationship between $R$ and $S$ and the relationship between $R$ and $T$ as if they were independent: the hypothesis actually means that

$$R=c\cdot\frac{S}T$$

for some constant $c$.

Thus, the relationship $R=c_1T$ holds only when $T$ is held constant, and the relationship $R=\frac{c_2}T$ holds only when $S$ is held constant.

You know that

$$\frac43=c\cdot\frac{3/7}{9/14}=c\cdot\frac37\cdot\frac{14}9=\frac23\,,$$

so

$$c=\frac{4/3}{2/3}=2\,.$$

When $R=\sqrt{48}$ and $T=\sqrt{75}$ we have

$$\sqrt{48}=\frac{2S}{\sqrt{75}}\,,$$

so

$$S=\frac12\sqrt{48\cdot75}=30\,.$$

Comment: Oh...... That's what it meant...

Comment: @1613585: Yep; it’s describing a simultaneous relationship amongst three quantities.